# Magento 2.2 B2B is community or enterprise release

Tags: magento2

Today I go through the magento 2.2 feature and very exciting all B2B feature are out of the box.

http://magentolive.com/in/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/05/MLI-2017_BO-III_Technical_Powering-Tomorrow_2.2.pdf

One question in my mind is it community edition or enterprise ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quote from a comment on a blog I found it seems that sadly **only the Enterprise version** gets any of the B2B functions.

The blog in mind: https://divante.co/blog/magento-2-2-b2b-features-case-study/

And the quote from the comment made by the author of the article:

> **Piotr Karwatka**: *...as we were said on Imagine Partner Summit, April this year, it
>   will be Enterprise only feature; it's not planned to include B2B
>   features in Community*